# viber problem with xkbcommon ERROR after upgrade viber from version 16.1.037 to 18.2.0.2

Tags: viber

At Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) I have working Viber version 16.1.0.37 and decide to upgrade it to the latest version (18.2.0.2).
Download it from the official viber page ([Download Viber for Linux Ubuntu](https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb))
and I run standard installation procedure:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i viber.deb 
[sudo] password for tedy58: 
(Reading database ... 569896 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack viber.deb ...
Unpacking viber (18.2.0.2) over (16.1.0.37) ...
Setting up viber (18.2.0.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
```

Process terminated normally without any errors, but when I try to start it not start anymore.
Then I try to start it from the installation directory:

`$ /opt/viber/./Viber`

```
qt.webenginecontext: 
GLImplementation: desktop
Surface Type: OpenGL
Surface Profile: CompatibilityProfile
Surface Version: 4.6
Using Default SG Backend: yes
Using Software Dynamic GL: no
Using Angle: no

Init Parameters:
allow-loopback-in-peer-connection  
application-name ViberPC 
autoplay-policy no-user-gesture-required 
browser-subprocess-path /opt/viber/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess 
create-default-gl-context  
disable-features DnsOverHttpsUpgrade,ConsolidatedMovementXY,InstalledApp,BackgroundFetch,WebOTP,WebPayments,WebUSB,PictureInPicture,AudioServiceOutOfProcess 
disable-setuid-sandbox  
disable-speech-api  
enable-features NetworkServiceInProcess,TracingServiceInProcess,NetworkServiceInProcess 
enable-threaded-compositing  
enable-usermedia-screen-capture  
in-process-gpu  
use-gl desktop 

xkbcommon: ERROR: Couldn't process include statement for 'us(phonetic)'
xkbcommon: ERROR: Abandoning symbols file "(unnamed)"
xkbcommon: ERROR: Failed to compile xkb_symbols
xkbcommon: ERROR: Failed to compile keymap
[19745:19777:0207/163441.884845:FATAL:xkb_keyboard_layout_engine.cc(640)] Keymap file failed to load: us-phonetic
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

It now ended up with the above mentioned errors!

Then I start old viber.AppImage (16.1.0.37) and it start normally and working

After that I download [viber.AppImage](https://download.cdn.viber.com/desktop/Linux/viber.AppImage) (version 18.2.0.2), but when I run, it gave me the same errors like upgraded one!

`$ ./viber18.2.0.2.AppImage`

```
/run.sh: line 17: [: too many arguments
qt.webenginecontext: 

GLImplementation: desktop
Surface Type: OpenGL
Surface Profile: CompatibilityProfile
Surface Version: 4.6
Using Default SG Backend: yes
Using Software Dynamic GL: no
Using Angle: no

Init Parameters:
  *  allow-loopback-in-peer-connection
  *  application-name ViberPC 
  *  autoplay-policy no-user-gesture-required 
  *  browser-subprocess-path /tmp/.mount_viber1vJhu0i/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess 
  *  create-default-gl-context  
  *  disable-features DnsOverHttpsUpgrade,ConsolidatedMovementXY,InstalledApp,BackgroundFetch,WebOTP,WebPayments,WebUSB,PictureInPicture,AudioServiceOutOfProcess 
  *  disable-setuid-sandbox  
  *  disable-speech-api  
  *  enable-features NetworkServiceInProcess,TracingServiceInProcess,NetworkServiceInProcess 
  *  enable-threaded-compositing  
  *  enable-usermedia-screen-capture  
  *  in-process-gpu  
  *  use-gl desktop 

xkbcommon: ERROR: Couldn't process include statement for 'us(phonetic)'
xkbcommon: ERROR: Abandoning symbols file "(unnamed)"
xkbcommon: ERROR: Failed to compile xkb_symbols
xkbcommon: ERROR: Failed to compile keymap
[24666:24702:0207/174947.609811:FATAL:xkb_keyboard_layout_engine.cc(640)] Keymap file failed to load: us-phonetic
../run.sh: line 80: 24666 Trace/breakpoint trap   ../Viber
```

I would appreciate any help on that issue if somebody meet the same problem.

By the way I submit a ticket in [viber Q&A help center](https://help.viber.com/en/article/supported-platforms) asking them to update Viber to libssl3 on Ubuntu 22.04, and they answer me that reset my account and I can enter on Desktop PC now.
Really on that Ubuntu 22.04 machine I install and run it now, but with that upgrade in Debian 11 (bullseye) I can't run it except the old  AppImage version (16.1.0.37).

With searching in [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438947/viber-does-not-open-in-lubuntu-22-04-problem-with-keyboard-layout-settings) I found simple acceptable solution of the issue.
In keyboard layout settings you should place (in my case Bulgarian) at first place in layout's order. (But I think that Serbian and other different than English languages may cause the same problem with xkbdcommon.) Every other place of languages' layout in settings menu will cause this errors.

Thanks @hopetech for the hint!

Comment: Other simple way I found is just switch the layout to the local language and start Viber. After start Viber switch it again on prefer layout.